# Mongo web client for CentOS

Tags: mongodb, centos

On OSX I am using MongoHub to work on my MongoDB instance. Our application is going to production, running on CentOS 6.5 server and for that I need a web based DB access management UI.
I can't find any available ones

Comment: Are you only after a web-based UI? There is a list of some common [Admin Interfaces](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/) in the MongoDB manual. I would also suggest considering desktop interfaces like [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) which has RPMs available.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rockmongo ?
(you have to install php first)

Not updated since a year but still a useful tool :

http://rockmongo.com/

Comment: Thanks I will take a look, but would prefer a nodeJS solution